# How to get the week number for day irrespective of the calender week number?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

how to get the week number for the day irrespective of the calender week in excel?

Iam looking for the column "nth_week_number" .In the below table "2/5/2018" will fall in the 2nd week of the Feb 2018 but It was a 1st Monday of that Month.
Someone please help to resolve this in excel.

```
| Date      | Weekday   | week _of_the_month | nth_week_number |
|-----------|-----------|--------------------|-----------------|
| 2/1/2018  | Thursday  | 1                  | 1st Thrusday    |
| 2/2/2018  | Friday    | 1                  | 1st Friday      |
| 2/3/2018  | Saturday  | 1                  | 1st Saturday    |
| 2/4/2018  | Sunday    | 2                  | 1st Sunday      |
| 2/5/2018  | Monday    | 2                  | 1st Monday      |
| 2/6/2018  | Tuesday   | 2                  | 1st Tuesday     |
| 2/7/2018  | Wednesday | 2                  | 1st Wednesday   |
| 2/8/2018  | Thursday  | 2                  | 2nd Thrusday    |
| 2/9/2018  | Friday    | 2                  | 2nd Friday      |
| 2/10/2018 | Saturday  | 2                  | 2nd Saturday    |
| 2/11/2018 | Sunday    | 3                  | 2nd Sunday      |
| 2/12/2018 | Monday    | 3                  | 2nd Monday      |
| 2/13/2018 | Tuesday   | 3                  | 2nd Tuesday     |
```

Comment: Are the answers you want those listed in the last column of your table? What have you tried, and where have you run into problems?

Comment: yes, last column of the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this formula in row 2 and copy it down:

```
=(ROUNDUP(DAY(A1)/7;0)&". "&TEXT(A1;"dddd"))
```

This will output 2. Thursday for example, formatting it as 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. would require a bit more work. Please note that you might have to change the semicolons `;` to regular commas `,` in an English version of Excel (I think).

**Edit:** Updated formula to fit your exact case, as suggested by @Ron Rosenfeld:

```
=(CHOOSE(ROUNDUP(DAY(B1)/7;0);"1st ";"2nd "; "3rd "; "4th "; "5th ")&TEXT(B1;"dddd"))
```

Comment: To format the numeric portion, I suggest `CHOOSE(ROUNDUP(DAY(A2)/7,0),"1st ","2nd ","3rd ","4th ","5th ")`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld That's a nice solution, thanks for that!